# Gnuplot and data gaps

Tags: gnuplot, missing-data

I have files like this one:

```
       C1       C2          C3               C4
       1001     134901      61001            625.10
       1001     134901      61002            700.34
       1001     134901      61003            621.64
       1001     134901      61004            807.25
.....
       1001     134901      61841              0.37
       1001     134901      61842              0.32
       1001     134901      81001              0.14
       1001     134901      81002              0.08
       1001     134901      81003              0.04
       1001     134901      81004              0.05
```

So please note column 3 (I think the problem is there), where numbers 6xxxx jump to 8xxxx nubers and they are NOT consecutive.

I am trying to display those data with this gnuplot script:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced size 1920,1000 font 'DejaVuSerif-Bold,25'
set palette defined ( 1 "blue", 2 "cyan", 3 "green", 4 "yellow", 5 "red" )

#############################################
# OUTPUT PLOT
#############################################

set output output_file

set title 'FIELD ST VS SOURCE RMS: RL '.rline 

set view map
set key off 
set pointsize .8
set size 1,0.75
set origin .05,.2

set xlabel 'C3' font 'DejaVuSerif,15' offset 0,-1
set x2label ' test' font 'DejaVuSerif,15'
set xtics 10000 font 'DejaVuSerif,8'
set xrange [61001:81842]
show xrange
set x2tics 200 font 'DejaVuSerif,8'

set yrange [1277:1845]
set ytics 20 font 'DejaVuSerif,8'
set ylabel 'C1' font 'DejaVuSerif,15' offset 5,0

set cbrange [0 : max]
set colorbox
set cblabel 'C4'.units font 'DejaVuSerif,15' offset -2,0
set cbtics font 'DejaVuSerif,8'

plot input_file using 1:3:4 with points lc palette pointtype 7
```

Unfortunately I get a picture with only x and y axes, the label but without any data displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the x axis range to

```
set xrange [61001:81842]
```

But the x values (column 1) in your data file are not in that range. Your y range is also mis-matched with the data values (column 3).  Let gnuplot autoscale the plot to your actual data.  Then if you want to restrict the range afterwards you can do so based on a working plot.

```
set autoscale xy
```